Web scraping from a hidden tab on a site using python
I'm using bs4 and selenium to scrape a land auction site (URL https://bid.hertz.ag/ui/auctions/112571/14320874) and I'm having trouble scraping the auction date and attachments links from within the 'BIDS' and 'DOCS' tabs. I think it's because the site recognizes a machine simulating the click on the tab, because my scraper recognizes the tab it needs to click but always crashes before it can do so.
I've used a headless browser, used .scrollIntoView() for the tab, tried time.sleep() to make it seem like a human is waiting to click on the tab, and I can't figure out how to get the information returned.
Any suggestions on how to get past that?

there's an api. you don't need selenium

but always crashes Can you show us one of these crashes?

you can get the target data easily by using their API endpoint:

bid_url = https://bid.hertz.ag/api/items/14320874/bids?bid_type=public&newer_than=
docs_url = https://bid.hertz.ag/api/auctions/112571?page=active

Sample Code:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

bid_url = 'https://bid.hertz.ag/api/items/14320874/bids?bid_type=public&newer_than='
docs_url = 'https://bid.hertz.ag/api/auctions/112571?page=active'

doc_resp = requests.get(docs_url).json()
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc_resp['terms']['legalese'], 'lxml')
print(f"Terms and Conditions: {soup.text.strip()}")
links = doc_resp['items'][0]['documents']
for i in links:
    links_details = [i['file_name'], i['url']]
    print(links_details)

bid_resp = requests.get(bid_url).json()
for i in bid_resp:
    details = [f"BIDDER: {i['anonymized_bidder_id']}", f"BID: ${i['amount']}", f"{i['placed_at']}"]
    print(details)

output:
Terms and Conditions: Please note a complete and final series of Bidding Instructions that includes sale-specific terms and conditions will be available prior to each auction sale, and will be read by the auctioneer, prior to the start of bidding on the day of the sale. 
ANNOUNCEMENTS MADE BY THE AUCTIONEER AT THE TIME OF SALE WILL TAKE PRECEDENCE OVER ANY PREVIOUSLY PRINTED MATERIAL OR ANY OTHER ORAL STATEMENTS MADE. All decisions of the Auctioneer are final.
This auction is open and public. Bids may come from persons bidding online, over the phone, or in attendance on-site from where the online sale is being administered. 
All bidders must be pre-approved by Hertz Farm Management/Hertz Real Estate Services (Hertz).
Hertz reserves the right to deny registration of any bidder if there is a question as to the person’s credentials, intent, or fitness for bidding. 
Hertz represents the Seller(s) in this transaction.
Bidding is not contingent upon financing, nor is it contingent upon any Buyer or Lender inspection.
Minimum bid increments are at the discretion of the auctioneer throughout the auction.
The successful bidder will be required to execute a Sales Agreement at the conclusion of the auction and submit the appropriate down payment in a timely manner as instructed by the Auctioneer.
The subject property is being offered under the sale-specific terms. Preliminary terms are provided in the printed and electronic versions of the auction brochure. Final terms will be provided prior to the beginning of bidding on the day of sale and will be included in the Real Estate Sales Agreement.
The information in the auction brochure was obtained from sources deemed reliable, but Hertz, its licensees, and its employees make no guarantees as to its accuracy.
Prospective bidders are urged to fully inspect the property prior to the auction and to rely on their own conclusions; doing so is the complete responsibility of each prospective bidder. Bidding is based solely upon bidder inspection and due diligence.
All real estate and any improvements are being offered and sold on an “As-Is, Where-Is, With ALL Faults” basis, without any warranties or representations, express or implied, as to the fitness for a particular use, access, water quality or quantity, physical or environmental condition. Neither the Seller(s) nor the Auction Company are warranting any specific zoning classification, location of utilities, assurance of building permits, driveway permits, or water or septic permits.
Any and all acreage figures, diagrams, and/or dimensions included in the marketing materials are based on information currently available but are not guaranteed.  All drawn property boundaries in the marketing materials are approximate.  Any soil productivity rating reference that is included in the marketing materials is based on the information currently available in the USDA/NRCS soil survey database, and these numbers are subject to change upon periodic update by USDA/NRCS.
['Decatur_120_000-3296-01(1).pdf', 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/bwpaperclip-production/item_documents/assets/000/122/305/original/Decatur_120_000-3296-01%281%29.pdf']
['HOW-TO__Register_for_Online_Bidding.pdf', 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/bwpaperclip-production/item_documents/assets/000/122/306/original/HOW-TO__Register_for_Online_Bidding.pdf']
['HOW_TO_Access_and_Navigate_the_Bidding_Platform.pdf', 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/bwpaperclip-production/item_documents/assets/000/122/307/original/HOW_TO_Access_and_Navigate_the_Bidding_Platform.pdf']
['HOW-TO_View_an_Auction_Livestream_Feed.pdf', 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/bwpaperclip-production/item_documents/assets/000/122/308/original/HOW-TO_View_an_Auction_Livestream_Feed.pdf']
['1-Bidding_Intructions.pdf', 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/bwpaperclip-production/item_documents/assets/000/123/997/original/1-Bidding_Intructions.pdf']
['3-DRAFT-Sales_Agmt.pdf', 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/bwpaperclip-production/item_documents/assets/000/123/998/original/3-DRAFT-Sales_Agmt.pdf']
['BIDDER: 33220397', 'BID: $11400', '2024-01-25T16:18:38.252Z']
['BIDDER: 33186525', 'BID: $11300', '2024-01-25T16:18:28.351Z']
['BIDDER: 33220397', 'BID: $11200', '2024-01-25T16:17:19.164Z']
['BIDDER: 33186525', 'BID: $11100', '2024-01-25T16:17:11.435Z']
['BIDDER: 33220397', 'BID: $11000', '2024-01-25T16:15:54.132Z']
['BIDDER: 33186525', 'BID: $10900', '2024-01-25T16:15:46.855Z']
['BIDDER: 33220397', 'BID: $10800', '2024-01-25T16:15:21.668Z']
['BIDDER: 33186525', 'BID: $10700', '2024-01-25T16:15:14.698Z']
['BIDDER: 33220397', 'BID: $10600', '2024-01-25T16:14:56.478Z']
['BIDDER: 33186525', 'BID: $10500', '2024-01-25T16:14:52.104Z']
['BIDDER: 33220397', 'BID: $10400', '2024-01-25T16:14:30.765Z']
['BIDDER: 33221110', 'BID: $10300', '2024-01-25T16:14:26.182Z']
['BIDDER: 33220397', 'BID: $10200', '2024-01-25T16:14:11.909Z']
['BIDDER: 33221110', 'BID: $10100', '2024-01-25T16:14:02.676Z']
['BIDDER: 33220397', 'BID: $10000', '2024-01-25T16:13:16.654Z']
['BIDDER: 33186525', 'BID: $9500', '2024-01-25T16:13:10.912Z']
['BIDDER: 33220397', 'BID: $9000', '2024-01-25T16:12:59.201Z']
['BIDDER: 33186525', 'BID: $8500', '2024-01-25T16:12:51.643Z']
['BIDDER: 33220397', 'BID: $8000', '2024-01-25T16:12:39.527Z']
['BIDDER: 33186525', 'BID: $7500', '2024-01-25T16:12:31.689Z']
['BIDDER: 33223332', 'BID: $7000', '2024-01-25T16:12:25.297Z']
['BIDDER: 33220397', 'BID: $7000', '2024-01-25T16:12:26.251Z']
['BIDDER: 33186525', 'BID: $6500', '2024-01-25T16:12:14.986Z']
['BIDDER: 33226058', 'BID: $6200', '2024-01-25T16:11:20.657Z']
['BIDDER: 33224742', 'BID: $6100', '2024-01-25T16:11:20.643Z']
['BIDDER: 33186525', 'BID: $6100', '2024-01-25T16:11:39.994Z']
['BIDDER: None', 'BID: $6000', '2024-01-25T16:11:30.421Z']


That's awesome, thank you! How did you get the bid and docs URLs?

Hey if you observe the request in your browser network tab then you will find both api requests made by your target apps, so always try to observe how web application making request via network tab of your browser

Sorry to keep asking questions, but do you know of a way to automate that process of grabbing the API endpoints URLs in python? I'm trying to make my scraper applicable to a few different sites and I want the end user to not have to input those links for every site they want to scrape.

Well It's most of the time javascript is the Key for API, at this time i don't have such explanation for this but you can use selenium with xpath, though this is actually slower compared to request but also need a target xpath to define, I have a great project in my mind about this but up untill now I'm lacking something about backend staff of modern app which is sadly API defined within js file, let's see

One last question! I found an answer to the last one myself, but I need to figure out how to scrape the auction date and the documents from agwestland (example URL
https://bid.agwestland.com/auctions/10080-harlan-county-combination-farm/multipar). The winning bid information isn't dynamically loaded so I don't think I'll need to use an API endpoint to grab that, but the attachments are hidden in the info tab under documents. I can't find the API endpoint for that myself, could you help me with that?

Ok let me see that one

{"operationName":"multiparBidHistory","variables":{"auction_id":"10080"},"query":"query multiparBidHistory($auction_id: String!) {\n  multiparBidHistory(auction_id: $auction_id) {\n    bids {\n      bid_id\n      bid_status\n      composition\n      combo_num\n      combo_num_display\n      is_top\n      is_winner\n      amount\n      winning_bidder {\n        user_display\n        user_id\n        country_code\n        __typename\n      }\n      created_at\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}"} try this GQL post body in this endpoint https://bid.agwestland.com/api

I figured out how to extract the bid information, but now I need to extract the attachment links for the agwestland site. If you have any advice I would greatly appreciate it, but I totally understand if not! Thank you for all your help!
